# Get the columns in a single query

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
   C1    C2  
   1     0   
   1     1
```

i want the count of rows where c1=1 and the count of rows where c2=0 in one single query instead of separate queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  sum(case c1 when 1 then 1 else 0 end) Count_c1,
  sum(case c2 when 0 then 1 else 0 end) Count_c2
from YourTable
```

Comment: This looks more complex than noise's answer, but potentially leaves a smaller work footprint on the database.

Comment: @OlegDok, Be carefull with John at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149759/multiply-combination-of-columns-based-on-a-column-value . Review the OP comments in other questions. Do you know if there is a way to treat with this kind of users? Sorry about communication channel but I don't know what is the right way to contact with a other user for this cases. regards.

Comment: @Per Its different queries and noise's one returns two rows with two columns - each result in its row while mine returns one row with two columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UNION` keyword:

```
SELECT "ones", COUNT(*) WHERE c1=1
UNOIN
SELECT "zeroes", COUNT(*) WHERE c2=0
```