# Multiply combination of columns based on a column value

Tags: t-sql, calculated-columns

How to multiply values of the columns based on the value in one column.

Example

```
   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
    10     10     10     casea (multiply col1 * col2)
    20     20     20     caseb (multiply col1 * col3) 
    30     30     30     casec (multiply col2 * col3)
```

A query like:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, total
```

would return

```
    10,10,10,casea,100
    20,20,20,caseb,400
    30,30,30,casec,900
```

Of course performance is an important issue as always.

Thanks for participating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
  Col1,
  Col2,
  Col3,
  Col4,
  CASE Col4 
    WHEN 'casea' then col1*col2
    WHEN 'caseb' then col1*col3
    WHEN 'casec' then col2*col3
  END AS Total
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I did some research before posting this question, and learned that this is a correct solution that would perform poorly.

Comment: @John For performance use other features such as persisted computed columns and so on. Or **review your schema and dataflow**

Comment: @John - Why do you think this will perform poorly? Doubt it will make a perceptible difference and probably cheaper to calculate than extra IO of storing it.